# CreateValidationResults doesn't see customFieldValue

Tags: java, jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am creating issue with atlassian jira plugin and want to add a custom field in it called `customfield_111`. When I run a validation with `validateCreate` then the result of class `CreateValidationResult` should have passed customField but it has not:

```
IssueInputParameters issueInputParameters = new IssueInputParametersImpl();

issueInputParameters
        .setProjectId(model.getProjectId())
        .setSummary(model.getSubjectBody())
        .setDescription(model.getMsgBody())
        .setReporterId(model.getUser().getKey())
        .setIssueTypeId(model.getIssueTypeId())
        .setComponentIds(Long.valueOf(11111))
        .addCustomFieldValue("customfield_111", "myvalue");


IssueService.CreateValidationResult createValidationResult = issueService.validateCreate(model.getUser(), issueInputParameters); 
// here the customfield_111 is null !!!
```

I have add a `customfield111` in jira settings for issue as label text and I can manually create issue with that field but how can I do it automaticaly with the code?

Answer (score 0):

The solution:
name of the custom field which we see in jira is only a label. The id of the field is set automatically by Jira and the id in code must be set to the same value.
In my example I need to change the customfield id 111 to 10432.